# Why D3 is not creating svg elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am not sure what am I doing wrong but I am trying to create data-driven `svg` `<rect>`. The code is following

```css
var x = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    x.push(Math.floor(100 * Math.random()));
};
const newData = x;

const s1 = d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(newData)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", (d, i) => { return d })
    .attr("y", (d, i) => { return i * 50 })
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("height", 40)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </link>
    <script src="_d3.js"></script>
    <nav>
        <h1>Hello Reader</h1>
        <h2>Day1</h2>
        <p>Monday</p>
        <h2>Day2</h2>
        <p>Tuesday</p>
        <h2>Day3</h2>
        <p>Wednesday</p>
        <h2>Day4</h2>
        <p>Thursday</p>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <h1>Current Period</h1>

        <svg width="900" height="600">

        </svg>

        <h1>YTD</h1>

    </main>


</body>

</html>
```

However, the above code does not create any `rect` at all whereas I was expecting to see 20 `rect`s inside

```
<svg width="900" height="600">

    </svg>
```

The above code returns this

[image: S1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your script (`_d3.js`) to just before the closing `</body>` tag. The `d3.select("svg")` must be returning an empty selection, because your script starts executing before the `<svg>` is rendered, so there's no `svg` to select. (For more, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup) about where to include your script tags)

```js
var x = []
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  x.push(Math.floor(100 * Math.random()))
}
const newData = x

const s1 = d3
  .select('svg')
  .selectAll('rect')
  .data(newData)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', (d, i) => {
    return d
  })
  .attr('y', (d, i) => {
    return i * 50
  })
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('height', 40)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <nav>
    <h1>Hello Reader</h1>
    <h2>Day1</h2>
    <p>Monday</p>
    <h2>Day2</h2>
    <p>Tuesday</p>
    <h2>Day3</h2>
    <p>Wednesday</p>
    <h2>Day4</h2>
    <p>Thursday</p>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <h1>Current Period</h1>

    <svg width="900" height="600"></svg>

    <h1>YTD</h1>
  </main>
  <script src="_d3.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```